# Missing Scottish Administrative Data in OS Opendata sets

Tags: shapefile, ordnance-survey, administrative-boundaries, os-opendata, scotland

I'm not sure if this forum is really the correct place to ask, but impertinence would lead me to believe that there may be some one on here that may know the answer.
I'm using the Ordnance Survey Open Data bdline_gb shape files to try to pull together some geographic coverage data for my organisation that covers England Scotland and Wales.
I'm working mainly with the Parish data set; because that's how ridiculously specific my organisation can be (I am determinedly prising them away from **part** parishes!). And fortunately England and Wales administrative Boundaries "build-up" from parishes (or communities in Wales). 
In the bdline_gb data set there is also very nicely the District, Borough, County and Unitary Authority shape files as well; so I can overlay to see where I have coterminous boundaries that no longer need to be down to Parish level.

Unfortunately Scotland doesn't [still] have Parishes; but additionally the data sets don't seem to include any ADMINISTRATIVE boundaries for Scotland, at least not in it's proper coded sense; just the filler polygons without the appropriate codes. 
I can get electoral data till it's coming out of every orifice just not Administrative-
does anyone know where I can source this?

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of a small amount of linking from this lovely article 
http://mapgubbins.tumblr.com/post/40533148684/open-data-or-not-a-hard-look-at-the-scottish-data-zone

I eventually found
http://statistics.gov.scot/def/concept/folders/themes/geography

NB
the OpendataScotland site is experimental only- it may well disappear in December 2014

Answer (score 1):

The [Scottish Neighbourhood Statistics](http://www.sns.gov.uk/default.aspx) shapefiles seem to share the same outer boundaries as the bdline_gb ‘scotland_and_wales_const_region’ data. It may not have a suitably open licence for your application, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but the [Scottish Government website](http://crtb.sedsh.gov.uk/spatialDataDownload/dload.asp) lets you download a Scottish set of 'Agricultural Parishes', (opendata) which are obviously not all current administrative boundaries but could be useful to you if you're going right down to parish level in England.